# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void sObjectsInsert(Integer) from the type AccountHandler

Tags: apex, class

Hi all new to Apex here completing Trailhead...

I am receiving the error in the title and can't seem to figure out why. Here's my apex class:

```
public class AccountHandler {
    public static void insertAccount(Integer value){
        Integer counter = 1;
        //create a list
        List<Account> addAccounts = new List<Account>();
        while(counter <= value){
        //display current counter value
        system.debug('Counter value before incrementing' + counter);
        //create a new account
        Account store = new Account();
        store.Name = 'Acme Inc n' + counter;
        store.AccountNumber = 'A00n' + counter;
        addAccounts.add(store);
        system.debug(addAccounts);
        //increment counter
        counter = counter + 1;
        system.debug('Counter value after incrementing' + counter);     
        
        }
        system.debug('Size of Account list:' + addAccounts.size());
        system.debug('Elements in Account List:' + addAccounts);
        //insert
        insert addAccounts;
    }
}
```

And here is my execution code:

```
AccountHandler.sObjectsInsert(3);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring a method `insertAccount()`:

```
public static void insertAccount(Integer value){
```

but you are calling a method `sObjectsInsert()`:

```
AccountHandler.sObjectsInsert(3);
```

You must change one or the other - either call the method as declared, or declare the method as called.